# Running Selenium Automated Scrips on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, selenium, raspberry-pi, scheduled-tasks

I’m relatively knew to the selenium package and have been using it for a couple weeks. My current script uses selenium to scrape data, I analyze the data by running a few tests, and if there is a datastring that passes said tests python texts me using Twilio. I’m currently using my mac to run all of this but I was looking to run this script every 5 minutes, headless, and on a platform such that I dont need to keep my computer on. I have been looking at some potential solutions and it seems as though running this on a headless raspberry pie is the right option. I was wondering if anyone see’s any potential problems with doing so as I haven’t seen a thread with someone using Twilio? And, I’ve encountered problems trying to set up a cron task to automate it on my mac because of selenium and was wondering if this will be possible on the pi (looking at the raspberry pi 4)? Sorry, if this is a little long winded, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Run the script though any CI CD tools like Jenkins ,GoCD,Gitlab in a scheduled job so that the script would run in every 5 minutes in Agent node specified and you don't have to keep your computer on.